# Add asp.net dropdownlist item from JavaScript causes page postback error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-ajax

The design is:

all elements are in an `updatepanel`.

click on a list of `<tr>` to fire a `JavaScript` function to add new `<option>` to the asp `dropdownlist`.

But,
when I click on other buttons to callback to the server, I get an error message:

> Uncaught
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Invalid postback or callback argument.
>   Event validation is enabled using
>   
>   in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

I understand the problem. I need to let server side know the change of the dropdownlist before any other `postback`.

Set validation as false won't work in this case, the dropdown will lose the new item anyway.

I did some researches, and the possible solutions:

1)Using `ViewState? Request Form?` could anyone give an example?

2)Add dropdownlist item in server side. But I want to make the whole tr row clickable to fire the event. Could I click on tr and fire eg. its first child `linkbutton` or a `linkbutton` in somewhere else.

3)I've tried `Jquery.ajax` and webmethod , it can fire server event but since all method are `static (shared)` , it doesn't allow me to edit the downdownlist instance.

Any kinds of solution will be helpful!!

Regards,

Comment: When clicking on the <tr>, does the custom Javascript function make a callback (ASP.NET-AJAX) to the server to update the dropdownlist? Or is it a client-only option add function that doesn't involve the server at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should trigger a server side event handler to update the list from javascript as described in this article. http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx