# How do I add an option to a dropdown list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to use the following code to add an option to a dropdown list in ASP.NET. Any ideas why this doesn't work? I tried Googling but can't figure out why this won't work.

What shoud the code do? I have an ASP.NET dropdown list. I want to access the dropdown list by name and add an item to the list. The item should have descriptive text of "Some Text" and a value of "123".

Thanks!

```
$("#ddlCategory").append($("<option>Some Text</option>").val(1).html("123"));
```

Comment: $("<option>Some Text</option>") is not a valid selector... Please read how to use selector in jquery...

Comment: try this one if you like to use javascript http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/06/06/add-items-in-drop-down-list-or-list-box-using-javascript/

Comment: This will not make it get stored in viewstate. Be sure you are not relying on normal postback behavior /viewstate if you do this. If you are, then you should expose a web method instead and call it asynch.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var newOption = "<option value='"+"1"+"'>Some Text</option>"; 
$("#ddlCategory").append(newOption);
```

Comment: This worked. I also changed from using the control ID to using a class name. The selector change did not work by itself.

Answer (score 9):

You can try

```
$("#ddlCategory").append($("<option value='123'>Some Text</option>");
```

Or

```
 $('#ddlCategory').
      append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value", "123").
      text("Some Text"));
```

2nd code snippet from this question [What is the best way to add options to a select from an array with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170986/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-options-to-a-select-from-an-array-with-jquery)

Comment: i would use `.val(123)` instead of `.attr("value", "123")`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested that 1) your jquery is correct and works in a flat HTML file and 2) that you are using the correct Id - ASP.NET changes Ids dynamically on elements that runat="server", so you might want to try:

```
$('#<%=ddlCategory.ClientID%>').append(...etc etc
```

That will get you the correct Id from the ASP.NET page class.

Comment: Remembered that during debug. I'm now using a class selector instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change it to

```
$("#ddlCategory").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "1").text("Some Text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add options to an ASP.Net dropdown list with client-side code is a bad idea. It introduces all sorts of postback problems. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024154/add-asp-net-dropdownlist-item-from-javascript-causes-page-postback-error) for more details. You should either populate the dropdown completely client side, or trigger a partial postback to fill the list.