# append values to asp.net dropdownlist with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I am trying to append a value with jquery but with the ways I am trying the option doesn't want to append. 
THis is what I am trying (for test purposes):

```
 $('#<%=btnSelectAgentAdd.ClientID %>').click(function () {              
                var myOptions = {
                    val1: 100,
                    val2: 'text2'
                };
                $('#<%=ddlAgentName.ClientID %>').append(new Option(myOptions.val2, myOptions.val1));             
             });
```

I also tried this:

```
 $('#<%=btnSelectAgentAdd.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                var mySelect = $('#<%=ddlAgentName.ClientID %>');
                var myOptions = {
                    val1: 100,
                    val2: 'text2'
                };
                $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    $('#<%=ddlAgentName.ClientID %>').append( new Option(text,val) );
});           
             });
```

And this:

```
 $('#<%=btnSelectAgentAdd.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                var mySelect = $('#<%=ddlAgentName.ClientID %>');
                var myOptions = {
                    val1: 100,
                    val2: 'text2'
                };
                $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
             });
```

None of them are working. 
Debugging with firebug shows that the error is happening on the last step when the values are to be appended to the dropdownlist.
Every advice is welcome.
Thanks, Laziale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.each(myOptions, function (val, text) {
    mySelect.append($('<option />', {
        value: val,
        text: text
    }));
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vp6yk/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var newOption = "<option value='"+"1"+"'>Some Text</option>"; 
$("#ddlCategory").append(newOption);
```

Reference [How do I add an option to a dropdown list using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997209/how-do-i-add-an-option-to-a-dropdown-list-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#<%=btnSelectAgentAdd.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                var mySelect = $('#<%=ddlAgentName.ClientID %>').append('<option value="100">yourtext</option><option value="100">yourtext</option>');

             });
```